# How to Add/ Save/ Publish Image on a Page in Silverstripe 4

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

A Silverstripe 4 project has an extended Page which automatically generates a "MetaImage" on save which should then be attached to the page. Example code below:

```
class ExamplePage extends \Page
{

  private static $has_one = [
    'MetaImage' => 'SilverStripe\Assets\Image'
  ];

  public function onBeforeWrite()
  {

    if ($this->MetaImageID == 0) {
      $metaObjectImage = new Image();
      $metaObjectImage->setFromLocalFile($tmpFolder.'/'.$fileName);
      $metaObjectImage->ParentID = $saveFolder->ID;
      $metaObjectImage->Title = $this->Title;
      $metaObjectImage->write();
      $metaObjectImage->doPublish();
      $this->MetaImageID = $metaObjectImage->ID;
     }

      parent::onBeforeWrite();
   }
 }
```

However the image is being connected to the "Stage" version, but not the "Live" version. MetaImageID is updated in the `ExamplePage` table in the database, but not the `ExamplePage_Live` table.

I'm guessing the issue is `$this->MetaImageID = $metaObjectImage->ID;` is not setting the relationship correctly, but I'm not sure how to change this so it does save to "Live" when ExamplePage is published.

Comment: In SS4 you might configure your DO that it "owns" the MetaImage, see https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/versioning/#dataobject-ownership-with-custom-relations . Then it will be published when you publish your DO